# DOMDocument missing in php5.6

Tags: php, opencart, domdocument, php-5.6, vqmod

I'm attempting to set up a store using opencart which i am honestly very new to.
I bought a theme and for some reason the team uses vqmod.
I was able to install the vqmod using:

> localhost/mystore/vqmod/install

and i get this response.

> VQMOD ALREADY INSTALLED!

Now, when i navigate to

> localhost/mystore

An error pops up saying

> DomDocument

The full error message is

```
VQMod::bootup - ERROR - YOU NEED THE PHP "DOMDocument" EXTENSION INSTALLED TO USE VQMod
```

After a little research, i figured i had to install the php5.6-xml and php7.0-xml which i have.

However the error is still showing.

I went into the vqmod code and noticed the section raising the error is this.

```
if(!class_exists('DOMDocument')) {
        die('VQMod::bootup - ERROR - YOU NEED THE PHP "DOMDocument" EXTENSION INSTALLED TO USE VQMod');
    }
```

which means there's a DOMDocument class i'm missing.

However, i have tried everything i've seen online.
From installing php-xml, purging php, installing php-dom,restarting apache2, checking phpinfo.

None of these seem to solve the issue.

How do i get the DOMDocument class?

Comment: Why are you using a php version from last millennium?

Answer (score 2):

I have solved this issue on PHP 7.2.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1 with bellow commands.

```
sudo apt-get install php7.2-xml
sudo apt-get install php7.2-mbstring
```

Answer (score 0):

[DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) is part of the PHP [DOM extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) along with libxml which are enabled by default hence should already be part of PHP. You may need to recompile PHP.

Comment: Have you checked it was not compiled with `--disable-dom`? You can check this with `phpinfo()` - http://php.net/manual/en/dom.installation.php

Comment: Under what section would this be cause i just searched the whole ``phpinfo()`` output for ``--disable-dom`` and it returned zero result.

Comment: At the top - 'Configure Command', however it seems this is a bug in PHP 5.6. Look for php5.6-xml with `apt-cache search php dom` - `apt-get install php5.6-xml` then restart Apache.

Comment: ``apt-cache search php dom`` returns 
``php5.6-xml - DOM, SimpleXML, WDDX, XML, and XSL module for PHP``

Comment: That is the package that should do it - `apt-get install php5.6-xml` and then restart Apache

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by JBES - apt-get install php5.6-xml
did work for me.

Answer (score 0):

> VQMod::bootup - ERROR - YOU NEED THE PHP "DOMDocument" EXTENSION INSTALLED TO USE VQMod

Best resolution which helped me is to write in PHP.ini:

```
extension=dom.so
```

This will solve the issue :)